# Connection information required to install a theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, wordpress-theming

I have installed WordPress on Linux with Nginx, But when I am trying to install the theme it asks me for FTP connection confirmation every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to my question first we need to change the ownership permission to access directories

```
chown -R www-data:www-data your-wordpress-directory
```

Now we remove secure permission to confirmation of connection to make it direct installations from wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Now we need to ensure the permission of the folder set or not

```
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```